# Oauth- getting refresh token

Tags: oauth2, python, refresh-token

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get a refresh token out of SFDC.

I'm currently able to authenticate via Oauth and can make queries. I'm trying to test for when a token expires by requesting a refresh token.

```
def get_refresh_token(customer):
    consumer_key = "my_consumer_key"
    consumer_secret = "my_secret"
    access_token_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'
    data = {
                'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
                'refresh_token' : 'refresh_token',
                'client_id' : consumer_key,
                'client_secret' : consumer_secret,
            }
    headers = {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }

    req = requests.post(access_token_url, data=data, headers=headers)
    response = req.json()
    return response
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the response `{u'error_description': u'expired access/refresh token', u'error': u'invalid_grant'}`

That said, the original token has not expired so my thinking is that I can't request a refresh token if the original is still valid. **Assuming that's the case: How do I go about expiring a token without revoking it?**

I can revoke tokens without issue but expiring them is a different matter. If I go to session settings my timeout is set to 15 mins in the org of the user authenticating via Oauth.

The alternative is that my post is incorrect in some way. Any help would be much appreciated

below is an example of the response I'm getting from sfdc when I request a token:

```
{
    u'access_token': u'00skljfdsksdfjklskjdf_protected_WySu8ko0pFcX3vLSOp7ww3qJ8VGADsue', 
    u'token_type': u'Bearer', 
    u'signature': u'Y+aiNE8isd_protected_+i9QRfA=', 
    u'issued_at': u'1478737367806', 
    u'scope': u'refresh_token api', 
    u'instance_url': 
    u'https://sifdata-test.my.salesforce.com', 
    u'id': 
    u'https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D410000_protected_AU/005410_protected_AC', 
    u'refresh_token': u'5Aep861HDR3iASSX_protected_JIgHyRWn.6oH6XKva0f76V5AxRE7YhZygZQg'
}
```

**note: The code below to obtain an authorization and refresh token works without issue.**

```
def callback(request):
    code = request.GET['code']
    consumer_key = "my_consumer_key"
    consumer_secret = "my_secret"
    redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000/callback'
    access_token_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'
    data = {
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
                'code': code,
                'client_id' : consumer_key,
                'client_secret' : consumer_secret
            }
    headers = {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }

    req = requests.post(access_token_url, data=data, headers=headers)

    response = req.json()
    return response
```

Answer (score 4):

You posted in your code that you are setting the value of `refresh_token` to `refresh_token`. It needs to be the refresh token you got in the access token response (`5Aep861HDR3iASSX_protected_JIgHyRWn.6oH6XKva0f76V5AxRE7YhZygZQg`). not sure if you replaced the actual refresh token with the words "refresh_token" but since you had no problem posting it later in your question just making sure

You can request a new access token even if the access token is not expired but that is not the best practice.

best practice is to:

1. Make resource request
2. If fails, use refresh token to get new access token

In order to get a refresh token returned in the response (When initially requesting an access token) you must include `refresh_token` in the **scope** and the connected app must allow offline access. I do not see a scope in your code

The request for the Authorization code would look like this:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx&prompt=consent&scope=' + encodingUtil.URLEncode('full refresh_token','UTF-8');
```

The request for the access token would then look like:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?code=xxx&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx
```

to revoke you would do a get to:

```
'/services/oauth2/revoke?token=xxx'
```

To get a new access token using the refresh token:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=xxxxx'&client_secret=xxx&refresh_token=xxx
```

Here is a full example of a visualforce implementation of oAuth to compare to:

[Oauth Implementation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85664/oauth-implementation/85679#85679)

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thanks for catching that. Was it only in the first line? updated it if so

Comment: I included an example of the response I'm getting from SFDC when I request an access token, it includes both an `access_token` as well as a `refresh_token` and the scope looks correct. It's currently returning `refresh_token`. Do I need to revoke the token before I can request a refresh?

Comment: @user3195487 No you do not need to revoke the access token before using the refresh token - Mainly because the access token SHOULD be expired before you request a new one. Regardless, you can request a new access token any time using the refresh token if you choose to not follow standard practices

Comment: @user3195487 - Hopefully this is not exactly what you are sending `&refresh_token=refresh_token` as in your code. I would assume that you just replaced the actual value but if not the value needs to be the refresh token

Comment: it's not, that's just there to hide the real thing.

Comment: Are you revoking the access token? If you revoke the access token the refresh token becomes invalid as well

Comment: Nope, haven't revoked any tokens

Comment: when I try `curl https://customurl-test.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?client_secret=my_client_secret&grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=my_client_id&refresh_token=token_provided_by_sfdc` I'm getting the same error as well `{u'error_description': u'expired access/refresh token', u'error': u'invalid_grant'}`

Comment: try login.salesforce.com instead of your instance url and check your connected app settings

Comment: @user3195487 Also, I do not use curl much but the example I see do not appear like you have. In addition to the login.salesforce.com type formatting like in this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickstart_connecting.htm - Its something outside of the URL (once changed to login......) because it does work..

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I too am banging my head against the wall trying to solve this issue

Comment: I am also facing exactly same issue. Tried everything tried by@shartshooter. Man did you found the solution??

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else stumbles upon this in the future - I was having a problem due to a setting in the Manage Apps > Connected Apps > Manage > Edit Policies.  Under oAuth settings, there is an option called "Refresh Token Policy".  Mine was set to expire immediately by default for the app I am developing. Please change it to **Refresh token is valid until revoked** to get your problem solved.

Also, I saw some posts asking to change the placement of your parameters like shifting client_id from header to body and all those stuff - actually, API won't consider that so whether they are in body or header both are fine.