# Invalid Authorization Code when trying to get a refresh token

Tags: oauth

I'm trying to connect to a Salesforce org with a refresh token but have failed so far and can't get it right.

For the moment, I'm using an access_token which is working fine. I'm getting it with the following request:
`curl https://MyInstance.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=password' -d 'client_id=consumer-key' -d 'client_secret=consumer-secret' -d 'username=my-login@domain.com' -d 'password=my-password'`

However, when I try to generate the refresh token with the following command:
`curl https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code -d 'client_id=consumer-key' -d 'client_secret=consumer-secret' -d 'username=my-login@domain.com' -d 'password=my-password' -d 'redirect_uri=xxx'`

I always get the error: `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid authorization code"}`

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

There is `Perform requests at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)` in the OAuth scopes so I think I'm using the wrong request maybe?

I looked at [Oauth- getting refresh token](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148015/oauth-getting-refresh-token) which seems to be close to what I'm looking for but can't get it to work.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some misunderstanding about how OAuth 2.0 flows work.

I'll be [referencing the official Salesforce documentation on OAuth Authorization Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5)

There are a number of different OAuth 2.0 flows that Salesforce offers. Each one has different requirements and offers different (but usually overlapping) features. I believe that in all cases, you need to present an *access token* in the "Authorization" header of the request you're actually trying to make. The different flows present different ways to obtain that access token.

The [refresh token flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5) doesn't directly give you authorization, it uses a refresh token given to you from another flow (either the Web Server flow or the User-Agent flow) to give you a new access token after the current access token you have expires.

The username-password flow is generally not recommended for anything other than prototyping, and it does not give you a refresh token.

It looks to me like you tried to skip through part of the Web Server or User-Agent flow. Both of those flows have you first make a call to `https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize` to get the authorization code that you would then include in your second call, the one to `https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` (to get the access token along with the refresh token).

Both the Web Server and User-Agent flows are *interactive* flows though. That is, you need to be able to redirect your user to a login page and have them input their own credentials and authorize your code to act on their behalf via the API.

Since you're using cURL, I assume that you're doing something closer to server-to-server communication (with no humans involved). In that case, you should look into the [JWT Bearer flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) which is one of the two flows I'm aware of that are headless (i.e. doesn't require human interaction), the other being the username-password flow which should generally not be used.

One of the common sumbling blocks with the JWT Bearer flow is that you need to go through a flow that can generate a refresh token once before the JWT flow can succeed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm trying to follow the web server flow here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5
But when I give the url to the user to 'Request an Authorization Code', once they log in, they get an error saying that `Required String parameter \u0027state\u0027 is not present`. I assume I have to pass the parameter 'state' in the request as well but we have no idea where to find the value expected by the salesforce app. Any idea where I can get it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it finally worked! I accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5

> refresh token flow renews access tokens issued by the OAuth 2.0 web server flow or the OAuth 2.0 user-agent flow.

That means you can not use it in combination with the password flow you are using now.

Probably the easiest way is to use the [user-agent flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5).
You will need to pass a redirect uri in your request and wait for the callback. The callback will contain an access and refresh token.

Note that the callback will come from your own browser so the callback uri can be on localhost and your server doesn't have to be accessible from the internet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm trying to follow the web server flow here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5
But when I give the url to the user to 'Request an Authorization Code', once they log in, they get an error saying that `Required String parameter \u0027state\u0027 is not present`. I assume I have to pass the parameter 'state' in the request as well but we have no idea where to find the value expected by the salesforce app. Any idea where I can get it?

Comment: The state parameter can be set by you and will be returned back so your server can distinguish different sessions. So you can set it to your sesssion id. If you have only one session while testing you can use any value you like.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! I will try that right away

Comment: Thanks a lot, it finally worked! I wish I could accept or upvote your answer as well but I accepted Derek's one as it was more complete