# Displaying an image in external website

Tags: api, images

I'm trying to display an image related to one of my objects. When querying through API I get this:
`<img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=<some_image_id>" alt="No doc linked" height="800" width="800" border="0"/>`

Now, when I'm logged in to SalesForce I can view the image from my browser using that url. But, without loggin-in I can't.

I've searched through the documentation but I couldn't find my legs and hands, it's very unclear to my taste.

My question is - **what do I need to do to be able to display an image on an external site** (using auth token or what have you - I just can't find the correct way)?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using rest or soap? Rest, you can use the oAuth response headers to get the instance URL.

Example of the rest headers returned with the access token

```
{
    "id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D50000000IZ3ZEAW/00550000001fg5OAAQ",
    "issued_at":"1296458209517",
    "scope": "id full api openid refresh_token chatter_api",
    "instance_url":"https://na1.salesforce.com",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "refresh_token":"5Aep862eWO5D.7wJBuW5aaARbbxQ8hssCnY1dw3qi59o1du7ob.lp23ba_3jMRnbFNT5R8X2GUKNA==",
    "id_token": "eyJhb...h97hc",
    "signature":"0/1Ldval/TIPf2tTgTKUAxRy44VwEJ7ffsFLMWFcNoA=",
    "access_token":"00D50000000IZ3Z!AQ0AQDpEDKYsn7ioKug2aSmgCjgrPjG9eRLza8jXWoW7uA90V39rvQaIy1FGxjFHN1ZtusBGljncdEi8eRiuit1QdQ1Z2KSV"
}
```

Then you can append the instance_url to the relative URLs received in your call.

If soap, you can use the endpoint in the session object to grab the endpoint IIRC

Comment: thanks for the fast reply! given I have my client access key and secret how do I get the token or refresh it? is there a documentation you can point me to?

Comment: Best resource out there is here: - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com - For a complete example of implementing oauth using Apex/VF as an example look here - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85664/oauth-implementation/85679#85679 -

Comment: another question - in the flow you described, where would I put the token I have in the image url?