# Callout - Unauthorized endpoint error

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, force.com-sites, httprequest

I am trying to get the access token over a controller that is connected to a Salesforce site. But I am having the below error message:

```
System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://sandbox-goku.cs87.force.com/services/oauth2/token
```

My controller:

```
 public class Mycontroller {
        public String accessToken {
            private set;
            get {
                if (accessToken == null) {
                    accessToken = RestUtil.getAccessToken();
                }

                return accessToken;
            }
        }
  }
```

Utility to get the access token:

```
public class RestUtil {
    private transient static String accessToken = '';

    public static String getAccessToken() {
        if (accessToken == '') {
            accessToken = fetchAccessToken();
        }

        return accessToken;
    }

    private static String fetchAccessToken() {
        HttpRequest authReq = buildAutHttpRequest();

        Http http = new Http();

        HttpResponse authRes = http.send(authReq);

        String accessToken = extractAccessToken(authRes);

        return accessToken;
    }

    private static String extractAccessToken(HttpResponse authRes) {
        Map<String, Object> authResult = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(authRes.getBody());

        return (String) authResult.get('access_token');
    }

    private static HttpRequest buildAutHttpRequest() {
        HttpRequest authReq = new HttpRequest();
        authReq.setEndpoint('https://' + URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost() + '/services/oauth2/token');
        authReq.setMethod('POST');
        authReq.setBody(buildAuthRequestBody());

        return authReq;
    }

    private static String buildAuthRequestBody() {
        String template = 'grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}&client_id={2}&client_secret={3}';
        String[] arguments = new String[]{
                AdminAuthContants.USER_NAME,
                AdminAuthContants.PASSWORD,
                AdminAuthContants.CLIENT_ID,
                AdminAuthContants.CLIENT_SECRET
        };

        return String.format(template, arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you even attempt to do a search on the error? It would have taken you less time to do that and fix than post the question. The error even specifically tells you what to do

Comment: -1 for not reading the error from me

Comment: @glls - Not sure what you are trying to say with your comment?

Comment: I have just attempted to run my method to get the access token and it is working in "Anonymous Apex".

Comment: @Cubancoffee - Also if you want to see a complete working example see this answer of a similar implementation-> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85664/oauth-implementation/85679#85679

Comment: @Eric,  was just pointing out to the op the reason why I downvoted the question prior it  being marked as duplicate

Comment: @glls - Ah, you meant **message** not *me*

Comment: yup =P , didn't do the @username, the comments populated to fast.

Comment: Since I  can get the access token by "Anonymous Apex".  Now I do not think the issue is with my code.

Comment: My controller is used along with the Salesforce sites, this means that the user that executes the controller is a "Site guest user", that is the reason why I am getting that error message, If I understand properly, it is not possible to perform API calls over apex code if the user is "site guest user":

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006778&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: @Cubancoffee - You are **not** correct. I have implemented many a API/oAuth implementation from sites pages. Give this a try: https://partial-appfrontier.cs19.force.com/GrantSupportAccess. In your link it specifies *only within apex code* which is allowed. You cannot do it from the page itself (Client side) using JS

Comment: +1 because google took me here rather than those 2 marked on top

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're hitting another endpoint via REST and, when you do that, SFDC wants you to whitelist that domain, even if it points back to another SFDC server.

Follow the directions, go to

`Setup->Security->Remote Site Settings`

and enter the domain

`https://sandbox-goku.cs87.force.com/`

You should then be able to call out

Comment: hehe, you beat me to it =P