# INVALID_SESSION_ID error when external app is calling GETmethod on salesforce

Tags: integration, authentication, oauth, session, httppost

I have created webservice class with Get method.
I have created Connected app and I have consumer key and consumer secret.But I don't have knowledge on how to use it.

When external app is calling they are getting  `<errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode> <message>Session expired or invalid</message>` .

How can I resolve this error.

Comment: How are they setting the token in request?

Comment: Actually I have just created OAuth and received Consumer Key and Consumer Secret.

Comment: Hi @TusharSharma,I have edited my question,Please have look now.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get the access token from the Connect app tokens.

Here is a sample code for your reference

```
public class oAuth_Controller{

private auth_response rt;

public pagereference auth_Step_1(){


    String auth_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize';
    String params =  
                        '?response_type=code' +
                        '&client_id=' + encodingUtil.urlencode('YOURCLIENTID','UTF-8') +
                        '&redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/apex/{YOURVFPAGE}' +                           '&prompt=consent' + 
                        '&scope=' + encodingUtil.URLEncode('full refresh_token','UTF-8') +
                        '&state=step2';
        pageReference pr = New PageReference(auth_url + params);
        return pr;
}

public pagereference auth_Step_2(){

    if(apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('state') != 'step2')
        return null;


    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    Http http = new Http();

    String auth_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
    String params =  
                        '?code=' + apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code') +
                        '&grant_type=authorization_code' + 
                        '&client_id=' + encodingUtil.urlencode('YOURCLIENTID','UTF-8') +
                        '&client_secret=YOURSECRET' + 
                        '&redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/apex/YOURVFPAGENAME';

    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(auth_url + params);

    HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req);

    rt = (auth_response)json.deserialize(resp.getBody(),auth_response.class);
    //Do something with the results
    return null;

}

public void getnewtoken(){

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    Http http = new Http();

    String auth_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
    String params =  

                        '?grant_type=refresh_token' + 
                        '&client_id=' + encodingUtil.urlencode('YOURCLIENTID','UTF-8') +
                        '&client_secret=YOURSECRET' + 
                        '&refresh_token=' + encodingUtil.URLEncode(YOURREFRESHTOKEN,'UTF-8');

    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(auth_url + params);

    HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req);


}



private class auth_response{

    public string refresh_token;
    public string access_token;

}
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="oAuth_Controller" action="{!auth_step_2}">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:commandButton action="{!auth_step_1}" value="Start oAuth" rerender="msgs"/>
  <apex:commandButton action="{!getNewToken}" value="Get new Token" rerender="msgs"/>
  </apex:form>

  <apex:outPutPanel id="msgs">
      <h1>Congratulations</h1>
      {!$CurrentPage.parameters.access_token}
  </apex:outPutPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Now using this access token you need to make request to your custom Rest endpoint then you will get expected details.

Your sample code would be

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer sessionId" "https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/MyRestContextExample/"
```

- Replace sessionId with the  element that you noted in the login response.
- Replace instance with your  element.
- Replace accountId with the ID of an account which exists in your organization.

[Step Two: Set Up Authorization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)

[Oauth Implementation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85664/oauth-implementation/85679#85679)

Comment: Thanks @Tushar, but Is it also possible to get access token using Postman or ARC.

Comment: @devsfdc yes using postman you can get access token.

Answer (score 1):

This below article is may be very helpful for you to resolve the INVALID_SESSION_ID issue.Please go through it.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205360&type=1

may be you have to do
Turn "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" OFF.

you may find this setting under Setup | Security Controls | Session Settings.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @RamAgarawal,I have edited my question,Please have look now.